# stride, padding в pyTorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, pytorch

Объясните с примерами, что такое padding, stride в свёрточных слоях нейронных сетей. Как работать с ними в [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/). Для конкретики приведу кусок кода:

```
nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, (kernel_heights[0], embedding_length), stride, padding)
```

Объясните (на картинке), что есть stride, а что -- padding?

Comment: [stride](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQYZaDn_kSg), [Padding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smHa2442Ah4)

Comment: https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic/blob/master/README.md

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Stride - определяет шаг фильтра по карте признаков (или изображению, если это первыйй слой). Если stride=1, то это значит, что фильтр будет помещен в каждое положение на карте признаков и из исходной карты признаков размером `CxHxW` (каналы x высота х ширина)  будет получена карта признаков того же размера. Если `stride=2`, то результат будет `CxW/2xHx2`.

padding - определяет насколько надо расширить карту признаков перед выполнением свертки. Как правило, это нужно, чтобы посчитать значение свертки с фильтром в положении на границе карты признаков. То есть если идет свертка с фильтром 7х7 (kernel_size=7), то надо сделать `padding=3`, чтобы карта признаков не ужалась после свертки.
Есть несколько вариантов чем расширять карту признаков, самый частый вариант это zero padding, т.е. расширение карты признаков нулями.

Работать в pytorch очень просто - надо просто указать нужный параметр.
В принципе документация (https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.1/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) раскрывает, как этим пользоваться, но, надеюсь, мой ответ проясняет немного детали.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).